# Listar um array dentro do array com Angular 4 ngFor

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Se alguém conseguir me ajudar. Eu tenho o seguinte array

```
[{resourceGroup: "grupo1", idsporgroup: Array(4)}
{resourceGroup: "grupo2", idsporgroup: Array(2)}
{resourceGroup: "grupo3", idsporgroup: Array(3)}
{resourceGroup: "grupo4", idsporgroup: Array(5)}]

idsporgroup[
{id: "123456", total: 4.04166666}
{id: "123456", total: 6.0833333199999995}
{id: "123456", total: 0.25804800000000006}
{id: "123456", total: 96}]
```

Estou passando um *ngFor="let a of consumoResourceG" e {{a.idsporgroup}} e só me aperece [object] se coloco {{a.idsporgroup.id}}nao aparece nada, ja converti em string e deu certo... mais preciso colocar o ID e o Total em lugares específicos do HTML.

tem que ficar
Grupo1

```
id: 0000 total: 000
id: 0000 total: 000
id: 0000 total: 000
```

Grupo2

```
id: 0000 total: 000
```

Grupo3

```
id: 0000 total: 000
id: 0000 total: 000
```

Tentando um ngFor dentro do ngFor mais sem muito sucesso.

Comment: O segundo for: `ngFor="let item of a.idsporgroup"`

Comment: a baixo do ngfor principal:<tbody *ngFor="let a of consumoResG.idsporgroup">
                                                            <tr>
                                                                <td>{{a.id}}</td>
                                                                <td>{{a.total}}</td>
                                                            </tr>
                                                        </tbody>

Comment: Posta seu html @Fernando! Onde você faz esses for.

Comment: Dá uma olhada nesse link aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29028840/angularjs-ng-repeat-array-in-array
Talvez a solução 2 pode ajudá-lo.

Comment: Opá Marconi na verdade comentei errado ontem, ja tinha dado certo, eu passei o HTML como tinha ficado. A baixo do ngFor principal passei o ngFor como vc tinha falado e deu certo, agora entendi o conceito. Obrigado